# Off canvas slider works with default about us, home, contact asp.net but not register and login

Tags: jquery, canvas, navigation, asp.net-4.5

I am developing an asp.net 4.5 project as a learning experience.  Server side stuff I have some experience with, but am quite new to jQuery.  I am trying to use an off canvas slider nav menu inside a content panel of a master page (not an update panel).  I have left the generic visual studio nav bar across the top for basic login functionality.  I was tinkering with a slidebars tutorial and it works great with the generic about us, home, and contact pages of the default vs 2013 express asp.net 4.5 web application template.  When I try to link to the register/login pages from the slider or if I just click them in the default nav bar, the code throws an error stating that "0x800a01b6 - JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'slidebars'"  I had the same problem earlier trying to do something similar with jQuery-aim.

the basic code for the function call is below:

```
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="slidebars/slidebars.js"></script>

    <script>
    (function ($) {
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $.slidebars();
        });
    })(jQuery);
</script>
```

I researched a suggestion from another post about avast security settings in ie but I don't have that installed as an add-on.  I tried setting a no-conflict statement right before the function code, but had the same problem.  Thought maybe the slidebars.js or css was not loading but why would it work on the non-login pages.  I looked at maybe some kind of partial postback issue but the error gets thrown initial loading of the page.  I am a total noob who knows just enough to be dangerous, so I apologize if there is a glaringly obvious solution.  If someone could give some input or point me in the right direction, it would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you.

Comment: Hi there, I'm the author of Slidebars. The plugin did initially have some problems with .net, but these should be fixed in later versions. What version of Slidebars are you using?

Comment: Hi adam.  I love slidebars and am learning a lot from working around with the code.  I am very thankful for people like you who share your gifts and allow the rest of us to learn.  I figured out te problem ... user error.  I had a conflicting javascript issue due to poor placement of some code/reference links.  Code works like a charm now.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

sorry not to have posted this as resolved.  I am a noob.  Slidebars code works great.  I just blew it with how I implemented it.  I had some code that was getting called and blocking slidebar access to the right resources.  Thank you to adam for responding.